# Is ‘half half’ ambiguous?

Tags: mathematics

1. 50-50

Ex) There are half half milk and water. = there are 50:50 milk and water.

2. 1/4

Ex) There is half half water. = there is 1/4 water.

Is it right?

Comment: Your examples aren't "ambiguous" - they're simply "not English". But many people will use the collocation *half **and** half* to refer to various mixtures containing equal quantities of two ingredients (same as ***fifty-fifty***, which implicitly refers to equal ***percentages***).

Comment: I just made a start! Include the word ***and*** if you want to use "half and half" rather than "fifty-fifty" to identify "equal mixtures". But forget about doing "math" (half of a half is a quarter), because native Anglophones don't normally do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but the way you're using it is wrong in both cases.

Firstly, we never use "half half" to mean 1/4 in American English.  The only way to use "half" to express "one quarter" would be to say **half of a half X**, like

> He drank half of a half gallon of milk

but it sounds a little unnatural and you would only use it if "half X" was already a fixed, known quantity, like a half gallon container of milk.  You could also say something was "halved and then halved again" to express that it was divided into a quarter part, like

> [In some cases, items are halved and then halved again to make four equal parts.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/clips/z6bq6sg)

---

We *do* use **"half X, half Y"** to express 50% of one thing and 50% of another, but you have to express it differently from your example.  It is used like

> [Half-and-half is simply an equal-parts combination of milk and cream. It is **half whole milk, half heavy cream**.](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-half-and-half-995712)

Comment: "we never use "half half" to mean 1/4 in American English". Or British English. Or Canadian English. Or any other English I have heard of.

Comment: @DJClayworth  I thought that was probably true but I didn't want to make a blanket statement I wasn't sure of.  :^)

Comment: @DJClayworth - Canadian English indeed doesn't use "half half".  However, it does use the term "double-double", but only to mean coffee with two measures each of cream and sugar.